# Combine multiple numpy arrays on coordinate system, each array defined by a location vector and 2 axis vectors

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have image data loaded in python that was recorded from multiple detectorpanels. I would like to recreate the original image by putting each panel at the correct location. The data from each panel is in the form of a numpy array and I know the location of the corner of each panel and and the unit vectors for each array. It should be possible to reassemble the image however I have no idea where to start.

I was thinking of using a large array as a lattice to place the arrays on however this seems a bit messy and would struggle with panels at an off angle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea I created dummy example but this should work:

```
import numpy as np
image_piece1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 2))
image_piece2 = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 2))
image_piece3 = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 2))
image_piece4 = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 2))
lst_images = [image_piece1, image_piece2, image_piece3, image_piece4]
coords = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
zero_array = np.zeros(shape=(4, 4))
for i in range(len(coords)):
    zero_array[2*coords[i][0]:2*(coords[i][0]+1), 2*coords[i][1]:2*(coords[i][1]+1)] = lst_images[i]
```

So basically zero_array will be your merged image.

I don't know exactly what you are looking for but this should give you the idea I beleive, as you asked for an idea.